# Change my existing Azure function App URL(Login/landing page url) with static (which i want to get redirected to previous one) one?

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

[image: Redirection to static URl]

I have seen the Azure portal for the same and referred various sources. It was mentioned to do the changes from Proxies section in Azure function App.

[image: Proxies]

Please let me know how it can be achieved?

Comment: What is the second url ? Another service not part of your azure function ?

Comment: hello @Thomas , second url is the Azure VM url (which is stopped now )which i want to hit and get the landing page of first URL (which is my Azure function), so i just want to get my redirection work by keeping the same URL for client. i hope i given my explanation.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? Sorry it is not that obvious for me ^^

Answer (score 0):

- According to this [**Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies), Versions 1.x to 3.x of Azure Functions support proxies and In-portal editing is not supported by all languages and operating systems.
- In such cases you can opt either for [**Azure API Management**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts) for your application or create a `proxies.json` file in the root of your function app manually.
- Alternatively, you can create a function app in .net 3.7 runtime version to enable `proxies` settings from portal.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Work with proxies in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#create)
2. [Azure Functions runtime versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cazure-cli%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#breaking-changes-between-3x-and-4x)